# What physics settings should be used to make a knot wrap up around itself?

Tags: animation, physics

I am trying to animate a fishing knot, and I need to know what physics to use to make the knot pulls on to tie up.

[image]
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/p5W0b6WLg-s

Comment: This animation looks too tidy to be done with physics, it was animated procedurally.

Comment: just give a Curve modifiers to a cylinder and move it along a curve that makes this shape

Answer (score 1):

You don't need physics here. Create a curve (begin with a *Curve Spirals > Archemedian*, you first need to activate the *Add Curve: Extra Objects* addon). Create a cylinder, give it an *Array* modifier with a low Count and a *Curve* modifier with the curve as *Curve Object*. Keyframe the *Array* modifier *Count* value:

[image]

[image]